# Why ionic nested ion-router-outlet not working?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing, ionic5

I want to use different layout in ionic 6.10.1. Here is my code.

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/account/account.module').then(m => m.AccountModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'folder/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./folder/folder.module').then(m => m.FolderPageModule)
  }
];
```

account.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AccountComponent } from './account.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './forgot-password/forgot-password.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AccountComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AccountComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [AccountComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class AccountModule { }
```

account.component.html

```
<p>
  account works!
</p>
<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
```

While navigating to route /account/login only account component data is showing. login, register and forgot-password data is not showing.

Comment: Can you try to declare the children of your **account.module.ts** directly into the children of account into **app-routing.module.ts**. Just to test if that works or not and try to locate the issue

Comment: I think in the first route you should use `CanLoad`, instead of `CanActivate`. With `CanActivate`, no matter if it returns true or false, the module will be loaded. `CanLoad` can prevent this. I'd also add in the first route object `pathMatch: 'full'`, or move it at the end of the array.